# Controlling the thickness of the tip of an arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a particular Dynkin diagram. Almost everything is going well except I can not control the thickness of the tip of the arrow. Is there any quick way to modify the last line of the code to control the thickness?

Also, is there any other smarter way to draw a double edge than the way that I have used? I have searched through the website but all the method seems too involved.

Here's my code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[roundnode/.style={circle, fill=black!100, very thick, minimum size=7mm},squarenode/.style={circle, draw=black!100, very thick, minimum size=7mm}]
\node[squarenode](1){};
\node[roundnode](2)[right= of 1]{};
\draw[very thick] (1)--(2);
\draw[very thick] (1)--(2);
\node[roundnode](3)[right=of 2]{};
\draw[very thick] (2)--(3);
\node[squarenode](4)[above right=of 3]{};
\draw[very thick] (3)--(4);
\node[squarenode](5)[below right=of 3]{};
\draw[<->,very thick] (4.east)..controls +(right:1.5cm) and +(right:1.5cm)..(5.east);
\draw[<->,very thick](1.north)..controls +(up:2cm) and +(up:2cm)..(3.north);
\draw[ ->,very thick,double distance=0.1cm](3)--(5);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

The figure I am getting is the following one.
[image: Want to control the thickness of the tip of the double-edged arrow]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The size of the arrow tip can be changed with option `arrows = {->[length=7pt]}`. This needs `\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta}`. But the double lines might need some fine-tuning, so they don't overlap with the tip.

Comment: Thanks! How to do the fine tuning?  Is there any command to draw a double or triple edged arrow in one stroke?

Comment: See the pgfmanual, ch. III, "Arrows"